# Android: Validating the EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, ontouchlistener

I am having 2 **`edittexts`** ans 2 **`imageviews`** and i want that the intent on the button click only works if both the edittexts have some value in it and and both the imageviews have been touched.
the problem with the following code is that when I run the application , intent is not working on the button click...

Sorry for poor formatting of code but here it is:

```
iv_other.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (event.getAction()) {

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
      {
    anim1.start();
    mp.setLooping(true);
    mp.start();
    tv_your.setText("SCANNING....");
    count++;
       }
    break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
       {
    anim1.stop();
    mp.pause();
    iv_other.setImageResource(R.drawable.animation_0);
    tv_your.setText("Thumb Impression Captured");      
        }
    break;
        }
    return true;  
        }
    });
 iv_your.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
          {
        anim.start();
        mp.setLooping(true);
        mp.start();
        tv_other.setText("SCANNING....");
        count++;
           }
        break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
           {
        anim.stop();
        mp.pause();
        iv_your.setImageResource(R.drawable.animation_0);
        tv_other.setText("Thumb Impression Captured");      
            }
        break;
            }
        return true;  
            }
        });
   converttostring();
    l1=yourname.length(); 
    if(l1!=0)
    {
        count1++;
    }
    l2=othername.length();
    if(l2!=0)
    {
        count1++;
    }
        while(count1>1)
    {
    result.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(count>1)
        {
                Intent next = new Intent("com.x9apps.compatibilityscanner.RESULT");
                startActivity(next);
        }   
    }
   });
    }
}
 private void converttostring() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      yourname =et_your.getText().toString();
      othername = et_other.getText().toString();
        }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onBackPressed();
        finish();
    }
```

These are the variables i am using..please help quickly
int count=0,l1,l2,count1=0;
static String yourname,othername;